# Is there a way to reload your page and THEN redirect it?

Tags: php, session

My page has a button that passes data to excel through a session. It exports the session information onto another page (which I cannot edit) and then downloads it.
The problem is, I want to reset the session every time I make this redirect, to make sure I get the right information every time.

For that, I thought about refreshing the page, and after that exporting the session through an window.open. But how would I do it?

Comment: session_destroy() followed by session_start() ?

Comment: Any question to which the phrase *"what have you tried?"* can be applied is not a great question for SO.

Comment: Can i do a session destroy() and session start() on a button click?